# issue in listview size small when it is inside scrollview android

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I want to integrate listview inside scrollview so below is my code

**xml file**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scl_add_task"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:visibility="gone" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_hjistory"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_save"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_history"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="#f2f2f2"

            android:layerType="software"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/img_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/list_history"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="POST"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect_orange"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
            android:visibility="visible" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When i run my code it look like below images

[image]

list view getting very small in height i want to it full height with full screen scroll.

Comment: avoid creating `listview` inside `scrollview`

Comment: listview inside scrollview is not good things

Comment: one option u can set the minimum height of the list view like  android:minHeight="40dp". please tell me if it is meet ur requirement

Comment: How big you want your list view to be? Should it be of a specific size like 100dp or as big as the height of screen?

Comment: listview in scrollview is not good idea, because of length and scroll problems, but you can do this with some efforts.

Comment: Could you please explain, what you are exactly trying to display above the listview ?

Comment: Abdullah :i want height till listview child loaded

Comment: another option u can simply implement is replace the listview with a linearlayour with orientation as vertical and using for loop u can inflate n no of view in side the linearlayout .

Comment: whit3hawks: i want to display list item data without scrolling problem both scroll should be seprate

Comment: Nithinlal : which way i can do this?

Comment: I post my answer please try

Comment: @user3547706 Based on your reply to my comment, I am assuming that you want display two separate scrollable views inside the parent view and make them scroll independently. To achieve that you can put both scrollview and listview inside a LinearLayout separately and control listview and scrollview height with the help of "android:layout_weight".

Comment: @user3547706 solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

hope this works for you..

Answer (score 1):

use this method.

```
  public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
          ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
              return;
        }

        int totalHeight = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
             View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
             if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             }
             listItem.measure(0, 0);
             totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
                  listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

this method will calculate total item hieght of view from adapter and set it to the listview

i dont remember from where i had got this solution or else i would have posted link of that answer. anyways thanx to that guy.

Comment: post your complete layout above

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Listview with linearlayout`<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listdemo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>`

in your code you u have to addd this method

```
  private void customListview() {

 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listdemo);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    for (int i = 0; i <20 ; i++) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview,null);
        linearLayout.addView(view);

    }



}`
```

item_recycleview is your layout of a single item of the list
count now set as 20 u can set as your wish

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `LinearLayout` set to vertical orientation instead of a `ListView`.

Normally a `ListView` is used for displaying a dynamic number of items given to it by an `Adapter` and the ListView will handle the scrolling for the items. When you put a ListView inside a ScrollView then both widgets will be in conflict over who handles the scrolling.

Setting the height of a ListView to `WRAP_CONTENT` doesn't work, because it has a dynamic number of items. The ListView wants to have a static height (such as `MATCH_PARENT` or `400dp`) and will scroll when needed and even create the item views on the fly when they become visible.

So use a LinearLayout and load it with child views yourself.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_history"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... snipped other attribs ... />
```

Since you already have an adapter that provides the views for the ListView you can use that to populate your LinearLayout:

```
    adapter = new YourAdapter();

    LinearLayout historyList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_history);
    for (int position = 0; position < adapter.getCount(); position += 1) {
        View itemView = adapter.getView(position, null, historyList);
        historyList.addView(itemView);
    }
```

Note: this is only a good solution if you know that your adapter will never provide a large number of items because you would then load your LinearLayout with a large number of views and things will grind to a halt or even crash.

If you cannot have a small number of items at all times then you will need to change your user interface. Perhaps you can just display the first 10 items only and when clicked go to a new activity that shows them all in a proper listview.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, another answer based on your comment: "I want to display list item data without scrolling problem both scroll should be separate."

Set your `ListView`'s height to a fixed amount:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_history"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    ... snipped other attribs ... />
```

This will allow the ScrollView to actually scroll the ListView and the ListView to scroll its own children.

Comment: how will u know that the height of the listview is 200dp .it changes the height dynamically.

Comment: ListViews want a fixed height. Normally you set it to MATCH_PARENT and it will fill the screen but you can also set it to a height of your choice. The ListView itself will be 200dp in my example, but the content of the ListView can still be dynamic depending on how many items the adapter provides it with.

Answer (score 0):

Putting listview in scrollview is not a good idea.

Add a listview header instead.

create new layout and put everything you have on top of listview in there.

Then inflate the layout and add it as listview header:

```
listView = view.FindViewById<ListView> (R.Id.ListView);
var header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
listView.AddHeaderView (header);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was here:
[londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/)
which says (quotes):

```
package net.londatiga.android.widget;
 
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Context;
 
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{
 
boolean expanded = false;
 
public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }
 
    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
 
    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
 
    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
            // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
 
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
 
    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

and then use it
myExpandableHeightListView.setExpanded(true);